# Migration From SQL Server Enterprise Edition to Standard Edition 2014 64 bit

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssas

Our Application using SQL Server Enterprise Edition, BI services (SSIS,SSAS,SSRS).My customer is restricted to SQL Server Standard Edition only.

**Now i have to migrate everything From EE to SE of SQL Server.**

1-While deploying SSAS (Semi-Additive measures are not supported)  ?
Might be i have fix this using Calculated Measures.

I am not sure about limitation with other services (SSIS, SSRS) could encounter while migration. Can somebody please help here !!!!!!
I have to move SSIS jobs,Reports Etc ...

Thanks

Veneet

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? 2008/2012/2014?

Comment: 1) Try posting this question on [here](dba.stackexchange.com).  2) For SQL Server Database Engine [sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280724.aspx) could help to find those features specific to Enterprise edition.

Comment: In't that what parallel testing is for :)

Comment: hey Paul ,SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is with the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx).  There are separate sections on SSIS, SSAS and SSRS.  The headlines are:

**SSIS**

Standard does not support *Change Data Capture Service for Oracle by Attunity* and *Change Data Capture Designer for Oracle by Attunity*.

**SSRS**

Standard does not support *Data driven report subscription*, *Scale out deployment (Web farms)*, *Alerting* and *Power View*.

**SSAS**

Standard does not support *Scalable Shared Databases*, *Semi-additive Measures*, *Perspectives*, *Writeback dimensions*, *Linked measures and dimensions*, *Proactive Caching*, *Push-mode processing*, *Direct Writeback* and *Measure Expressions*

Comment: I also come across this link but is telling about operational data.

[link] https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2108/identify-database-features-restricted-to-a-specific-edition-of-sql-server-2008/